# How to display time stamp as date in higcharts?

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, highcharts

I am building an application where it gets the data from facebook api and the graph is generated using the HighCharts.

The graph is generated successfuly, but the date i get is in the time stamp format. How can i convert it to the actual date format.

Here is the code:

```
 xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
```

**Data:**

```
   series: [{"data": [["2015-11-15T08:00:00+0000", 55], ["2015-11-16T08:00:00+0000", 45], ["2015-11-17T08:00:00+0000", 32], ["2015-11-18T08:00:00+0000", 54], ["2015-11-19T08:00:00+0000", 34], ["2015-11-20T08:00:00+0000", 1]], "name": "page_views"}, {"data": [["2015-11-15T08:00:00+0000", 23], ["2015-11-16T08:00:00+0000", 67], ["2015-11-17T08:00:00+0000", 54], ["2015-11-18T08:00:00+0000", 23], ["2015-11-19T08:00:00+0000", 64], ["2015-11-20T08:00:00+0000", 23]], "name": "page_stories"}, {"data": [["2015-11-15T08:00:00+0000", 23], ["2015-11-16T08:00:00+0000", 64], ["2015-11-17T08:00:00+0000", 34], ["2015-11-18T08:00:00+0000", 32], ["2015-11-19T08:00:00+0000", 43], ["2015-11-20T08:00:00+0000", 43]], "name": "page_fan_adds"}]
```

Here is the application in [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/bhok22bz/)

Comment: When you load your data, then in preprocessing you need to interate on each item and convert by Date.parse / date.utc. In the output you receive timestamps.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks for the reply, i know that will work, but i want to know if there is a direct way to bind in highcharts

Comment: At this moment there is not build-in parser for data, you can post your suggestion in our uservoice here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if we can fetch the date in any format from facebook API.
I had in the past converted the date in my code once i retrieve the same.

Below is what i had implemented with VB.NET.

```
  DateVariable.ToString().Substring(0, 10)).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
```

Hope this helps you.